# Java method that produces an object

Tags: java, methods, parameters, uml, class-diagram

I have to follow the below UML diagram to design a programme.

The programme is supposed to generate 2 random integers, and ask user for input the answer to the sum of said integers.

However, I am not sure how to make use of the method `static void getTwoIntegers(MyInteger m, MyInteger n)` , or what to put inside it.

I have tried initialising 2 `MyInteger` objects with `MyInteger int_1 = new MyInteger(m);` and `(n)` in this method, but get a "cannot be resolved" error everytime I call its getter method `int_1.getInteger();`

And since the method `getTwoIntegers` is void, I cannot just return 2 random integers.  I'm truly stuck on how to utilise this method

Any ideas? Thanks so much

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple demo of what your implementation can accomplish.

The `MyInteger` objects passed as parameters (`m` and `n`) can be modified by the implementation of `getTwoIntegers` using the `setInteger` method of the class.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyInteger a = new MyInteger(333);
        MyInteger b = new MyInteger(444);
        System.out.println("before: " + a.getInteger() + "," + b.getInteger());
        
        getTwoIntegers(a,b);
        System.out.println("after: " + a.getInteger() + "," + b.getInteger());
        
    }
    
    public static class MyInteger {
        private int val;
        public MyInteger() { val = 0; }
        public MyInteger(int v) { val = v; }
        public void setInteger(int n) { this.val = n; }
        public int getInteger() { return val; }
    }
    
    static void getTwoIntegers(MyInteger m, MyInteger n) {
        // in your case modify implementation to produce random numbers
        m.setInteger(222);
        n.setInteger(555);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
before: 333,444
after: 222,555
```

Answer (score 2):

[Gardener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73392372/3723423)'s answer nailed it.  For the records, I'd like to share some more thoughts.

This class diagram is misleading.  The parameters of an UML operation have a *direction* that should be indicated in front of the parameter name.  It can be `in`, `out`, `inout`.  If the direction is omitted in the diagram, UML assumes that it's an `in` argument.  Which assumes that the parameter is not muted by the operation.

If it would have been correctly specified as `getTwoIntegers(out m: MyInteger, out n: MyInteger)` (yes, UML syntax order is slightly different from Java),  you would have understood that the values of m and n are provided for the output of the values of the operation, and not as input.  And indeed, as Gardener explained, in Java you can provide a class object  that can then be mutated to store the results; because class objects are passed by reference (i.e. it's the same object that is used and not a copy). This is by the way why a class `MyInteger` is used in this lab instead of a built-in type `int`.

Other unrelated UML remarks:  there is no `static` type modifier keyword in UML.  Either is it marked as `{static}` or is it underlined.  Last but not least,  there should be no multiplicity on a dashed dependency arrow. Multiplicities are for associations, i.e. structural relationships.

Comment: Misleading is the wrong word. _Wrong_ (syntactically) would be the right one. P.S. The name of the other poster is spelled incorrect...

Comment: @qwerty_so Thanks. Syntactically, it’s indeed definitively wrong. I used misleading for the additional semantic contradiction, because the semantics of the default direction says something that is incompatible with the only way to solve it. Fortunately, Java has a different understanding of the directions and fortunately it can be solved with the Java semantics. But the same diagram transposed in some other language might not work so well (e.g. C++ where `in` parameters are either passed by value or as `const&` whereas `out` and `inout` would require references (or pointers))

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think in UML, objects are passed by reference as well, unless their types are data types. So, if you have `myOperation(in myObject: myClass)`, then myOperation may modify the object referred to by myObject, but not the reference itself. Instead, `myOperation(out myObject: myClass)` means that myOperation may modify myObject to be a reference to a different object.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl indeed UML has reference semantic for object that are not «datatype». This means that any such object known by the operation could be modified. And that’s exactly my point here:  out should have been mentioned explicitly, because the direction constraints the way objects can be used despite the fact that it may be passed by reference anyway.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl sorry I reread your comment and realize that I missed an important point. The specs describe  the in, out and inout in terms of values. My understanding is that an out can only be about values in the attributes of the out object, and not the reference to an out object. Also, some papers of the UML founders refer to the inout and out to replicate mecanisms in existing languages that do not allow multiple return objects.

Comment: I don't think this the intended interpretation. Whether the attributes are modified is not determined by the parameter direction, but by the ParameterEffectKind (see section 9.4.3.4 of the UML spec). For example, an 'out' parameter may have ParameterEffectKind = Create. How would you interpret that? I think the method creates an object and then returns a reference to that object as the value of the 'out' parameter.